# Calculating variance using Laplace approximation for GP classification

Tags: gaussian-process, laplace-approximation

I'm having some trouble implementing Algorithm 3.2 from Rasmussen and Williams.

[image: Algorithm 3.2]

Namely, sometimes when I evaluate step 6, I obtain a negative variance, which I believe is impossible (and makes line 7 fail). I think I'm doing something wrong, but I can't figure out what it is.

Here is my code (sorry there's so much of it):

```
self.f_hat = self.find_F(var_p=self.var_p)
self.W = self.hess (self.f_hat)
self.W_root = scipy.linalg.sqrtm(self.W)
l = len(self.Y)
Ky = np.matrix (self.K*self.var_p)
self.L = np.linalg.cholesky (np.matrix(np.eye(l))+self.W_root*Ky*self.W_root)
self.grad = np.matrix(np.diag(self.grad_log_logistic_likelihood (self.Y, self.f_hat)))
f_bar = k*self.grad.T
v = np.linalg.lstsq(self.L, self.W_root*k.T)[0]
var = k_star - v.T*v

def find_F (self, var_p=1, guess=None, threshold=.0001, evals=1000):
    """Calculates f_hat according to Algorithm 3.1 in RW

    Returns:
        f_hat (pd.Series)
    """
    l = len(self.Y)
    if guess ==None:
        f_hat = pd.Series(np.zeros(l))
    elif len(guess) == l:
        f_hat = guess
    else: 
        exit ('Initial guess must have same dimensions as Y')
    K_mat = var_p*np.matrix (self.K)
    for i in range (evals):
        # find new f_hat
        W = self.hess (f_hat)
        W_root = scipy.linalg.sqrtm(W)
        f_hat_mat = np.matrix (f_hat)
        L = np.linalg.cholesky (np.matrix(np.eye(l))+W_root*K_mat*W_root)
        b = W*f_hat_mat.T + np.matrix(np.diag(self.grad_log_logistic_likelihood (self.Y,f_hat))).T
        a = b - W_root*np.linalg.lstsq(L.T,np.linalg.lstsq(L,W_root*K_mat*b)[0])[0]
        f_new = K_mat*a
        f_new = pd.Series([f.item() for f in np.nditer(f_new)])
        # find error between new and old f_hat
        sq_error = sum([(fh-fn)**2 for fh,fn in zip (f_hat, f_new)])
        if sq_error/sum([fn**2 for fn in f_new]) < threshold:
            return f_new
        f_hat = f_new
    exit ('Maximum number of evaluations reached without convergence')

def log_logistic_likelihood (self,Y, F):
    """ Calculates the log logistic likelihood of the outcomes Y given the 
    latent variables F. log[p(Y|f)]
    Uses Equation 3.15 of RW

    Parameters:
        Y (Series): outputs, +/-1
        F (Series): values for the latent function

    Returns: 
        lll (float): log logistic likelihood 
    """
    lll = math.log(np.prod([self.logistic_likelihood(y,f) for y,f in zip(Y,F)]))
    return lll

def grad_log_logistic_likelihood (self,Y,F):
    """ Calculates the gradient of thelogistic likelihood of the outcomes 
    Y given the latent variables F. 
    Uses Equation 3.15 of RW

    Parameters:
        Y (Series): outputs, +/-1
        F (Series): values for the latent function

    Returns: 
        glll (np.matrix): diagonal log likelihood matrix
    """
    l = len(Y)
    glll = np.matrix(np.zeros([l,l]))
    for i in range(l):
        glll[i,i] = (Y[i]+1.)/2. - self.logistic_likelihood(1.,F[i])
    return glll

def hess (self,F):
    """ Calculates the negative Hessian of the logistic likelihood according to 
    Equation 3.15 of RW
    Parameters:
        F (Series): values for the latent function

    Returns: 
        W (np.matrix): diagonal Hessian of the log likelihood matrix
    """
    l = len(self.Y)
    W = np.matrix(np.zeros([l,l]))
    for i in range(l):
        pi_i = self.logistic_likelihood(1., F[i])
        W[i,i] = pi_i*(1-pi_i)
    return W
```

Comment: Let's look at the two terms used to compute var.  1) You don't show how k_star is computed.  2) Presuming Stefano M's comment on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12580019/solve-singular-value-decomposition-svd-in-python is correct, np.linalg.lstsq, which is used to compute v, is based on SVD, so it should be fairly robust numerically, but I have no first-hand knowledge of that, and I haven't checked that you called it correctly.

Comment: Can you try higher precision calculations, at least quad precision, but preferably something like 100 digits, to see if there's a difference in the leading digits?